# Is the HTML5 source element bug fixed for iPad 2?

Tags: html, ipad, video

According to this page:

http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody#webm

The first iPad has a bug that prevents it from reading more than one `<source>` element for HTML5 video. I would assume this is fixed in iPad 2, but can anyone confirm this or provide a source link that confirms this?

Comment: As @Paul points out, it has nothing to do with the hardware -- iPad 1, iPad 2, or hypothetical iPad 3 -- it's about the operating system. iOS 4.0 was released July 2010, and most devices have that OS or later.

Comment: @Matthew: very true, although that said, I think a user has to try pretty hard to get iOS 3.2 running on an iPad 2. OS and hardware are a bit more entangled on the iPad than on, say, a PC.

Comment: @Paul Sure, but I figure if your goal is to (a) write or modify your website so that it uses more than one `<source>` element, or to (b) decide whether to buy an iPad 2 based on its handling of multiple `<source>` elements, what you need to know is that anything running 4.0 or later will work, which includes the iPad 2. I can't come up with any other reason for asking, and in either case knowing that an iPad 1 with iOS 4.0 works as well is useful info.

Comment: @Matthew: oh definitely, I just wanted to point out that with the iPad, the hardware can pretty much determine the minimum OS you're running, so it's not entirely accurate to say that the question has nothing to do with the hardware. As you say though, the salient issue is the OS version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html#ios), this bug is fixed in iOS 4.0.

[iPad 2 initially shipped with iOS 4.3](http://blogs.pcmag.com/miller/2011/03/apples_steve_jobs_unveils_ipad.php), so yup, this issue is fixed for iPad 2.

(And any iPad 1 users who experience the issue just need to plug their iPad into their internet-connected computer to upgrade their OS.)